# Spring Add Profile at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to add a profile at runtime based on some environment variable, so I have `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` and in code I have

```java
if(someCondition){
  springApplication.additionalProfiles("mock-test");
}
```

If `someCondition` is true, was expecting active profiles to be "local", "mock-test" but its in reverse order?

`INFO o.s.b.SpringApplication : The following 2 profiles are active: "mock-test", "local"`

Anyway to make `mock-test` as last profile?

Comment: Any specific reason to get mock-test at last?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal So if it’s PR branch deployment we have an environment variable set as “pr”. In that case I want to use wiremock endpoints to run functional tests (provided in application-mock-test.properties file)